# Python : Reshaping a numpy array of 3d images and labels

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to reshape numpy array of (1397,2)  into (1397 , 50,50,20,1).The array has  2 columns

```
each row  in column1 is of length: 50*50*20  [3D image]
each row in column2 is of  lenght : 2 [labels : [0,1],[1,0]].
```

Basically trying to unpack the 1st column of 3d images to feed into an input layer in a CNN.

My code so far

```
np.array([i[0] for i in data]).reshape(-1,50,50,20,1)
```

Gives me an error :

```
"ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1397 into shape (50,50,20,1)"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Cheers 
Robin

Comment: Is the first column a Tensorflow object?

Comment: Nope , just a numpy array with 50*50*20

Comment: What's the `dtype` of this array?  If `data` has mixed columns like this it is either object dtype, a structured array, or a list rather than an array.  We need an accurate desciption.

Comment: The whole array is a dtype object , but for the specific column of 50*50*20, is of dtype float 64

Comment: Evaluate that expression piece by piece, checking the results at each step.  Something isn't behaving as you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking of writing a loop extracting each 50*50*20 from each row and append it to an array 1397 times, will that give me  1397 * 50*50*20 or will that smudge all into one as a single 1397 as before?

Answer (score 0):

Ok as it turns out the all the rows in column 1 were not of the same shape. one was of 17*50*50 instead of 20*50*50 . Its all good now :)

Thanks to Michael!